# Domain not resolving to elastic IP amazon linux

Tags: dns, amazon-route53

I pointed my domain name that I registered through route 53 here: Response returned by Route 53

```
DNS request sent to Route 53
arcadeidea.com.     IN     A
EDNS0 client subnet IP
24
DNS response code
NOERROR
Protocol
UDP
Response returned by Route 53
34.214.33.108
```

And when I try going to the elastic IP (34.214.33.108) I get the hello world html page served by a sample

```
arcadeidea.com’s server DNS address could not be found.
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN
```

I think it may be a problem with port forwarding, as I'm forwarding 80 to 8080 which is what the sample node app was setup as a default. Not sure how to debug that though...Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

This DNS server is not answering for this domain. Check that you have inserted the correct AWS DNS hosts on your domain registrar.

```
% nslookup
> server NS-1316.AWSDNS-36.ORG
Default server: NS-1316.AWSDNS-36.ORG
Address: 205.251.197.36#53
> arcadeidea.com              
Server:     NS-1316.AWSDNS-36.ORG
Address:    205.251.197.36#53

** server can't find arcadeidea.com: REFUSED
```

Comment: I was able to resolve this problem by restarting my router. Still works in 2017 boys

Answer (score 0):

So what worked for me was resetting my wireless router...my other computer that was directly plugged into the modem was able to load the site after associating the IP with the domain, but not the computer that was wired to my router. I was able to verify this when I used my phone to check the site, while connected to my wireless router's network...Network admins, I understand a little more of your pain now.

Comment: I checked your DNS configuration based on the whois for the provided domain arcadeidea.com and it was configured incorrectly. Resetting your modem did not have anything to do with it.